# How to add Custom Fields in Registration Page using Liferay6.2?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay

I need to know about to add custom fields in registration page using Liferay 6.2.

For Ex : i need to add another Fields like Phone Number , Qualification etc.

I am new Liferay.So Please suggest me to add custom fields in registration page using Liferay 6.2?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is one wiki page at Liferay for achieving the same, have a look at this [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+Fields+and+JSP+Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the custom attributes and give add,update permissions for guest role
2. override the create_account.jsp and add the below code
   [image]
3. Override the addUser method of CreateAccountAction.java class using EXT. In that method you will have the code to add the user. After adding the user insert the below code.

   User user = UserServiceUtil.addUserWithWorkflow(....)
       //add below code
       user.setExpandoBridgeAttributes(serviceContext);//adding the retrived attributes to user
       UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user);//update the user

Attached image to 2nd point as liferay tags are showing in stackovrflow preview.
To know about custom fields in detail [visit](https://www.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/working-with-liferay-custom-fields)